# How to add content that already exists on another #div:before

Tags: javascript, css

How to add content that already exists on another #div:before
because the existing div will I set as a fixed position

```css
#text-1{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  /* visibility:hidden; */
  /* position:fixed; */
  }

#text-2 {
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  }

#text-2:before {
  content:"Equal to the contents of #text-1";
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  color:#ff0000;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  left:50%;
  background-color:#e3e3e3;
  border-top:1px solid #999999;
  margin-left:-50%;
  margin-top:18px;
  font-style:italic;
 }
```

```html
<div id="text-1">Content Text-1</div>
<div id="text-2">Content Text-2</div>
```

Comment: No, this is not possible especially with CSS and Js will have trouble addressing pseudo-elements.

Comment: Regarless, pseudo-elements are for **styling** NOT actual content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jquery for this. First include jquery library in your html file if it is not there and then add below javascript code inside your head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var contents = $("#text-1").html();
    $("#text-2").html(contents);
});

</script>
```

Comment: This has roughly the same *effect* as the OP's pseudo-code but is not actually adding the text to a pseudo-element. Good Solution though.